# Апач отображает пхп код вместо того чтобы его исполнять

Tags: php, linux, apache, centos

Поставил в виртуалке CentOS 7, в него lamp (httpd и mariadb как обычно, а php 7.2 из remirepo). Столкнулся с этой проблемой не выполнением скрипта, а выводом содержимого файла. В чем может быть дело?

Comment: Как поставил? Скрипты , свой код, поштучно, ансибблом, папетом, чефом, из докера, из лэкси из вагоанта из тераформ...? У всех как обычно по разному... я вот через pxe сервер ставлю на железо. Дайте больше данных если заинтерисованы в быстром ответе.

Comment: @Hellseher ручками. Просто открыл виртуалку в виртуалбоксе и все поставил через yum. Я не умею пока работать со всеми этими продвинутыми инструментами типа ансибла.

Answer (score -2):

Надо включить php модуль:

```
$ a2enmod php7.2
```

А затем не забудьте перезапустить апач:

```
$ service apache2 reload
```

Comment: Подчеркиваю: CENTOS, тут нет a2enmod, это не убунта.

Comment: Проверьте в файле конфигурации httpd.conf  строки 
  `<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>`

Comment: Уже делал так. Не помогло.

Comment: Неплохо было бы написать что вы уже делали. `LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp7.so` тоже смотрели?

Comment: Так тоже делал (да - я тоже умею гуглить). У меня от этой последней строки апач не перезапускается.